Why does an image is made of many images?
I download an image and I show it using Python.
image = imread('spheres.jpg')

print(image.shape)#(398, 429, 3)


As we can notice, the image shape has 3 dimensions. What are the three images it is made of ?
In this case, the image that I downloaded is:

We can plot the 3 images it is made of:
plt.imshow(image[:,:,0])
plt.imshow(image[:,:,1])
plt.imshow(image[:,:,2])





The last dimension indicates the number of channels the image has. The channels can represent multiple things, but generally these are the RGB (red, green, blue) channels of the image. The linked wikipedia page also mentions other colour representations such as HSV and YUV.
